# Is the response of Sir Oswald Mosley to the letter of Bertrand Russell's 1962 letter recorded?

Tags: mathematicians

In 1962, Sir Oswald Mosley, leader of the British Union of Fascists which he founded in 1932 (disbanded in 1940) made overtures towards  Bertrand Russell on engaging in a public debate - according to some commentators I've read online.

Russell penned a reply -  reproduced below:

> Dear Sir Oswald,

> Thank you for your letter and your enclosures. I have given some thought to our recent correspondence. It is always difficult to decide how to respond to people whose ethos is so alien and in fact, repellent to one's own. It is not that I take exception to the general points made by you but that every ounce of my energy has been devoted to an active opposition to cruel bigotry, compulsive violence, and the sadistic persecution which has characterised the philosophy and practise of fascism.

> I feel obliged to say that the emotional universes we inhabit are so distinct, and in the deepest way opposed, that nothing fruitful or sincere could ever emerge from association between us.

> I should like you to understand the intensity of this conviction on my part. It is not out of any attempt to be rude that I say this but because of all that I value in human experience and achievement.

> Your sincerely,

> Bertrand Russell

**Q. Is there any indication of the topics which Mosley was hoping to debate with Russell?**

It's unlikely to be fascism - which I've seen a number of commentators state, given the defeat of fascism throughout Europe by the Allies. I do know that after the 1958 Notting Hill riots he stood in the 1959 General Election for Kensington North on a stridently anti-immigration platform calling for forced repatriation of Caribbean immigrants and a ban on mixed marriages and was defeated. And again in 1961, he took part in a debate at UCL (University College London) on immigration from the Commonwealth.

**Q. Is there any indication how Mosley took this rejection?**

Comment: The typewritten letter appears to have been reproduced as a scan [here](https://lettersofnote.com/2016/02/02/every-ounce-of-my-energy/), for example.

Comment: The [correspondence](https://bracers.mcmaster.ca/bracers-basic-search?search_api_views_fulltext_3=&search_api_views_fulltext_4=&search_api_views_fulltext_1=Mosley%2C+Oswald&search_api_views_fulltext_2=&search_api_views_fulltext=&search_api_views_fulltext_6=&sort_by=search_api_aggregation_2&sort_order=ASC) is stored in the Bertrand Russell archive at McMaster University. There is no mention of a debate in the publicly available summary, just a request for a conversation over lunch: "1962/01/11; Mosley wants to lunch privately with BR about their differences."